# Limit of a subtration of two sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to solve the following question:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. Determine if the following is true or false:
>
> If $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=2$$
>
> Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-n)=\infty$$

I know that $(a_n)$ has to be an infinite sequence, since if it were finite, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$$

I think that the correct answer is true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Hint: eventually, $a_n/n>1.5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\left| \frac{a_n}{n} - 2\right| < \frac 12$$

for $n$ large enough. Then

$$\frac{a_n}{n} - 2 >-\frac 12 \Rightarrow \frac{a_n}{n}-1 > \frac 12 \Rightarrow a_n - n > \frac{1}{2} n . $$

Comment: Yes, that inequality is the same as $-\frac 12 < \frac{a_n}{n} - 2 < \frac 12$. @Alan

Comment: The first inequality is because $\left| \frac{a_n}{n}-2 \right| < \frac{1}{2} $, which implies $-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{a_n}{n}-2<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Thank you, it is very clear now.